# NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:

Tags: lua, nmap, winpcap, port-scanning

I'm new to VAPT and I'm using GUI for windows, this is what I got when I used this script from nmap online guide [nmap -p 80 --script http-default-accounts.routers xx.xx.xx.xx]. I borrowed the script from here : https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-default-accounts.html

[nmap -p 80 --script http-default-accounts.routers xx.xx.xx.xx]

Nmap output begins below this line:

NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap/nse_main.lua:823: 'http-default-accounts.category' did not match a category, filename, or directory

stack traceback:

[C]: in function 'error'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap/nse_main.lua:823: in local 'get_chosen_scripts'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap/nse_main.lua:1315: in main chunk

[C]: in ?
QUITTING!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nmap uses the `--script` option to introduce a boolean expression of script names and categories to run. To provide arguments to these scripts, you use the `--script-args` option. So what you wanted to run was: `nmap --script http-default-accounts --script-args http-default-accounts.category=routers`

In most cases, you can leave the script name off of the script argument name, as long as you realize that another script may also be looking for an argument called `category`. For example: `nmap --script http-default-accounts --script-args category=routers`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this command:

```
nmap --script vulscan.nmap-vulners -sV {target}
```

Then use the following command instead.

```
nmap -sV --script vulners {target}
```

For me, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As for Nmap 7.90 [2020-10-03] [changelog](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#7.90), dealing with directories has changed:

> [GH#2051]Restrict Nmap's search path for scripts and data files. NMAPDATADIR, defined on Unix and Linux as ${prefix}/share/nmap, will not be searched on Windows, where it was previously defined as C:\Nmap . Additionally, the --script option will not interpret names as directory names unless they are followed by a '/'. [Daniel Miller]

So basically if we said you are using kali and this is your old command:

```
nmap --script vulscan -sV ###.###.###.###
```

It should become like:

```
nmap --script vulscan/ -sV ###.###.###.###
```

adding a `/` after directory name.